# How to check most recent tweet via command line on Linux?

Tags: notification, twitter

I have a highly active Twitter account that I sometimes write replies to. Whenever I can, I try to reply to it right away. Twitter has a feature that allows you to get notifications whenever someone tweets, but I have noticed that sometimes it lags for about 30 seconds.

I was thinking of using a program that checks what the most recent Tweet sent was to reduce the lag. I tried using `wget` and `lynx` and that did not work because it did not support JavaScript.

*How do I get the most recent Tweet sent by a Twitter account? I know how to do the rest.*

Comment: If you use the twitter api, all of the scripting should be done server-side, no?